# A relationship from the AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a new post in my site, but for some reason, EF throws the following error:

> A relationship from the 'PostAttributeValue_Definition' AssociationSet
>   is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a
>   corresponding 'PostAttributeValue_Definition_Source' must also in the
>   'Deleted' state.

Since I'm not trying to delete anything and I didn't changed or removed any value, I'm confused why I'm getting this error.

My db context contains the following:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostAttributeValue>().HasRequired<PostAttributeDefinition>(a => a.Definition).WithOptional().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapKey("RelatedAttributeDefinitionId");
        }).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        /* Category(required) to PostAttributeDefinition(many) */
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostAttributeDefinition>().HasRequired<Category>(a => a.OwnerCategory).WithMany(c => c.AttributeDefinitions).Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapKey("OwnerCategoryId");
            }).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

My publish method looks like this:

```
    //
    // POST: /Post/Publish/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Publish(int? id, PublishViewModel model)
    {
        if (!id.HasValue || id.Value < 1)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var category = this.categoryService.Find(id.Value);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<PostAttributeValue> attributes = new List<PostAttributeValue>();
            foreach (var attribute in model.Attributes)
            {
                attributes.Add(new PostAttributeValue()
                {
                    Definition = attribute.Definition,
                    RawValue = attribute.Value.Serialize()
                });
            }

            Post post = new Post()
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                Description = model.Description,
                City = model.City.City,
                Brokerage = model.Brokerage,
                Location = model.Location,
                RequestedPrice = model.Price.Value,
                ParentCategory = category,
                Attributes = attributes,
            };

            this.postService.PublishPost(post);

            return RedirectToAction("ImageSelection", new { id = post.PostIdentifier });
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

The error is been thrown from the Repository class Add() method, which looks like this:

```
    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        try
        {
            var result = this.Entity.Add(entity);
            this.context.SaveChanges();
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            var deletedEntries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Added && e.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Because the exception related to entities in deleted state, I've wrote this linq query that checks for entities that're not unchanged or added, but it returns zero results... I really 
don't know why I'm getting this error.

Just to note, I'm using proxy entities, and from inspection in the debugger everything seems OK - the entire values are been filled in as excepted.

Hope somebody can help me figure it out. Thanks! :)

Edited:

The PostAttributeDefinition model class, which is a class that describes a custom attribute definition (each category can have different custom attributes - for example, "TV Shows" can have a custom attribute "Number of episodes" while Movies "IMDB rank", for example)

```
public class PostAttributeDefinition
{
    #region Members

    private Lazy<object> lazyDataValue = null;
    private Lazy<PostAttributeDefinitionValidationRules> lazyValidatorValue = null;
    private Type cachedDataType;

    #endregion


    /// <summary>
    /// The filter name
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int DefinitionId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The owner category
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public virtual Category OwnerCategory { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The filter title
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Metadata enum that provides extra data about the data type
    /// </summary>
    public PostAttributeTypeMetadata TypeMetadata { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bitwise metadata that provides data about the object in display mode
    /// </summary>
    public PostAttributeDisplayModeMetadata DisplayModeMetadata { get; set; }

    public PostAttributeEditorType EditorType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The attribute raw default value
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public byte[] RawDataValue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The attribute raw associated validation attributes
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This field is used only by EF.
    /// YES - It's against DDD rules, and I need to seperate it. setting it in TODO.
    /// </remarks>
    public byte[] RawValidationRules { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is this field required
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This field does not relate to the validation rules since we should check it
    /// only in creation / modification of the post and not in search for example.
    /// </remarks>
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The attribute validators
    /// </summary>
    public PostAttributeDefinitionValidationRules ValidationRules
    {
        get
        {
            if (lazyValidatorValue == null)
            {
                lazyValidatorValue = new Lazy<PostAttributeDefinitionValidationRules>(() =>
                {
                    if (this.RawValidationRules == null || this.RawValidationRules.Length == 0)
                    {
                        return new PostAttributeDefinitionValidationRules();
                    }

                    return this.RawValidationRules.Deserialize() as PostAttributeDefinitionValidationRules;
                });
            }

            return lazyValidatorValue.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RawValidationRules = value.Serialize();
            this.lazyValidatorValue = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the stored object data type
    /// </summary>
    public Type ValueDataType
    {
        get
        {
            //  Make sure we've loaded the serialized value
            if (lazyDataValue == null)
            {
                RetriveDataValue();
            }

            return cachedDataType;
        }
    }

    #region Value content

    /// <summary>
    /// Store the attribute default value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TType">The default value type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">The default value</param>
    /// <returns>Fluent style writing - returning the same object</returns>
    public PostAttributeDefinition StoreDataValue<TType>(TType value)
    {
        //  In case of empty value, we need to defaultize it
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = value.DefaultizeNullableValueForSerialize<TType>();
        }

        //  Store as bytes
        RawDataValue = value.Serialize<TType>();

        //  Reset the lazy cached value
        lazyDataValue = null;

        //  Fluent style returned value
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrive the item default value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TType">The item default value data type</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The item default value</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown in case the raw value is null or empty.</exception>
    public TType RetriveDataValue<TType>()
    {
        return (TType)RetriveDataValue();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Retrive the item default value
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The item default value</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown in case the raw value is null or empty.</exception>
    public object RetriveDataValue()
    {
        //  Make sure that we've loaded the lazy value
        if (lazyDataValue == null)
        {
            lazyDataValue = new Lazy<object>(() =>
            {
                //  Deserialize
                var value = RawDataValue.Deserialize();

                //  Remve defaultize in case we've done that (by the way, we're caching the type
                //  in order to retrive it in case of null value)
                value = value.ReverseDefaultizeNullableValueForDeSerialize(out cachedDataType);

                //  Return it
                return value;
            });
        }

        //  Return the cached lazy data value
        return lazyDataValue.Value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The PostAttributeValue class, which I wish to save and causes the problems is:

```
public class PostAttributeValue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The attribute value id
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int AttributeValueId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The value owner post
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Post OwnerPost { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The value attribute definition id
    /// </summary>
    //public int RelatedAttributeDefinitionId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The value attribute definition
    /// </summary>
    public virtual PostAttributeDefinition Definition { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The stored raw value
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] RawValue { get; set; }


    #region Value content

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if there's anything stored in the raw value
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Boolean value indicates if there's anything stored in the raw value</returns>
    public bool HasValue()
    {
        return RawValue != null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrive the item value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TType">The item default value data type</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The item value</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown in case the raw value is null or empty.</exception>
    public TType RetriveValue<TType>()
    {
        return (TType)RetriveValue();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Retrive the item value
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The item value</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown in case the raw value is null or empty.</exception>
    public object RetriveValue()
    {
        if (RawValue == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not deserialize the value since there's nothing in the raw value.");
        }
        return RawValue.Deserialize();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note that I'm using a ViewModel for the attributes (model.Attributes is an IEnumerable)

```
public class PostAttributeViewModel
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Editable(false)]
    public PostAttributeDefinition Definition { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DefinitionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DefinitionVertificationToken { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

The Definition attribute, that I'm assigning and mapping to the PostAttributeValue model is auto-filled by EF.

Comment: Could you post the class model. It looks like the statement `Definition = attribute.Definition` "steals" away a Definition, leaving an association in the deleted state. But it's a bit hard to tell without class model. There seem to be some redundant associations there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll check it again. I've updated the original post with the models code :).